# Install the latest even-numbered node with nvm?

Tags: node.js, nvm

It's recommended that you install the latest [even numbered node](https://tamalweb.com/which-nodejs-version), since:

> You should always use even-numbered versions marked LTS that says “Recommended for Most Users” on the download page.

[and](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/):

> After six months, odd-numbered releases (9, 11, etc.) become unsupported, and even-numbered releases (10, 12, etc.) move to Active LTS status and are ready for general use.

Is there a way (preferably a one-liner) to install the latest even numbered node without having to even [look it up](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/)? (yeah, that's lazy, but it avoids any chance of human error, and also allows docs to remain up to date for years, since something like `nvm install 16` will require updating in the future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nvm install --lts` is how you do it. [Here are the docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#long-term-support) for even more fun details.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I had hoped for. Will accept in 13 minutes.